# .NET 4.0 Cast Generic Interfaces

Tags: .net, generics, interface, casting

I have two Interfaces, one of them is a generic one, allowing only Types that derive from the second Interface. They look like this:

```
public interface IProvider<T> where T : IContent
{
    T getContent(int i);
    void addContent(T content);
}
public interface IContent
{
    string whatIAm();
}
```

Of course my real Interfaces are more complex but it is enought to show what my problem is.
Now i have for each interface a concrete class:

```
public class Provider : IProvider<FileContent> 
{
    public FileContent getContent(int i)
    {
        return null;
    }
    public void addContent(FileContent content)
    {
    }
}

public class FileContent : IContent{
    public string whatIAm(){
        return "FileContent";
    }
}
```

And in my code i want to work with the reference type "IProvider" but the cast goes wrong... Please look at this example:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Provider p = new Provider(); //works
        IProvider<FileContent> pp = p as IProvider<FileContent>; //also works
        IProvider<IContent> ppp = pp as IProvider<IContent>; //fails :(
    }
```

`ppp` is always null. What do i have to change that this cast is working?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This could be a duplicate of [Casting an object to a generic interface](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/222403/casting-an-object-to-a-generic-interface).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The type argument must match exactly. `IProvider<IContent>` is a different type than `IProvider<FileContent>`, there is no inheritance between them.

Imagine you have an `IProvider<IContent> ppp`  from your `IProvider<FileContent>` and a developer tries `ppp.addContent(someOtherContentThatIsNoFileContent)`. That statement is valid for `IProvider<IContent>`, but it would break type safety, so not allowing such a conversion is the right thing to do.

[Covariance and Contravariance for generic type parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233059) allow something like this under certain circumstances, but since your interface uses the type parameter both as in- and output parameter, this won't apply to it the way it is declared right now.

**EDIT:** Look at `IEnumerable`'s definition:

```
public interface IEnumerable<out T>
```

So you know IEnumerable uses `T` only as output parameter (you can't add items, only enumerate them), and the `out` keyword specifies that `T` is covariant. So you can do

```
IEnumerable<String> strings = new List<String>();
IEnumerable<Object> objects = strings;
```

If you want to do this, you would have to remove the `add` method from your interface. Same applies for input parameters and the `in` keyword on generic type parameters.

Your interface would then look like this:

```
public interface IProvider<out T> where T : IContent
{
    T getContent(int i);
}
```

Comment: exactly this is what i want to reach.
As i already wrote in the question:
What do i have to change that this cast is working?

I already tried to remove one of the two methods in IProvider Interface - but it doesn't matter which one i remove, the cast still does not work :(

Comment: @user1531730 The comment was getting too long, I updated my answer.

Comment: @user1531730 Good to hear. :) I guess you'll need to split your interface into two interfaces then.

Answer (score 3):

This isnt the way generic work in C#. A generic of `IProvider<FileContent>` is not a subtype of `IProvider<IContent>`.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote

```
Provider p = new Provider(); //works
IProvider<FileContent> pp = p as IProvider<FileContent>; //also works
IProvider<IContent> ppp = pp as IProvider<IContent>; //fails :(
```

Let us assume that all three of these work. Then it would be possible to write the following:

```
ppp.addContent(new NonFileContent());
```

where `NonFileContent` is a class that implements `IContent`, but is not derived from `FileContent`.

Now, imagine what happens in the following call:

```
FileContent fc = pp.getContent(0);
```

The object that was just added is supposed to be returned. However, it's a `NonFileContent` instance, not a `FileContent` instance. Therefore, returning this object from a method whose return value has to be a `FileContent` instance is impossible, which is why the compiler does not consider `pp` and `ppp` assignment-compatible in the first place.

Comment: ok, i think begin to understand why it is not working.
But refered to the link Botz3000 posted, it should be possible if i remove the `void addContent(T content);` Method from the interface - but that also does not work.