# c# Interfaces - Implicit Conversion Error?

Tags: c#, interface

If I have this interface:

```
public interface IFoo : IDisposable
{ 
    int PropA {get; set;}
    int PropB {get; set;}
}
```

And a class:

```
public class Foo : IFoo
{
    public int PropA {get; set;}
    public int PropB {get; set;}

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose();
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}
```

Shouldn't this work without a 'Cannot Implicitly Convert' error?

```
    private Context context = new Context();
    private GenericRepository<IFoo> FooRepo;

    public GenericRepository<IFoo> Article
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.FooRepo == null)
            {
                this.FooRepo = new GenericRepository<Foo>(context);
            }
            return FooRepo;
        }
    }
```

I thought I had it right, what is the correct way to do this?

Comment: `this.FooRepo = new GenericRepository<IFoo>(context);`

Comment: you can use this approach: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/222403/casting-an-object-to-a-generic-interface

Comment: General rule of interfaces: use the class type only for construction; use the interface type everywhere else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're trying to do (assigning `GenericRepository<Foo>` reference to a field of type `GenericRepository<IFoo>`) would only work if `GenericRepository<T>` were [*covariant*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx) in its generic type parameter. For that, `GenericRepository<>` would be defined as:

```
public class GenericRepository<out T> {...} //note the "out" modifier.
```

then this assignment would be OK:

```
this.FooRepo = new GenericRepository<IFoo>(context);
```

However, **that won't work** because covariance is limited to *interfaces* and *delegates*. So, in order to play within that limitation, you can define a covariant `IGenericRepository<T>` interface and use the interface instead of the class:

```
public interface IGenericRepository<out T> {}
public class GenericRepository<T> : IGenericRepository<T> { }

private Context context = new Context();
private IGenericRepository<IFoo> FooRepo;

public IGenericRepository<IFoo> Article
{
    get
    {
        if (this.FooRepo == null)
        {
            this.FooRepo = new GenericRepository<Foo>(context);
        }
        return FooRepo;
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if `GenericRepository<T>` implements `IEnumerable` you can use the `Enumerable.Cast<T>` method:

```
public IGenericRepository<IFoo> Article
{
    get
    {
        if (this.FooRepo == null)
        {
            this.FooRepo = new GenericRepository<Foo>(context).Cast<IFoo>();
        }
        return FooRepo;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to implicitly convert context to Foo and not it's interface. Also, is Context implementing IFoo? If it is, this should work.

Try this:

```
private Context context = new Context();
private GenericRepository<IFoo> FooRepo;

public GenericRepository<IFoo> Article
{
    get
    {
        if (this.FooRepo == null)
        {
            this.FooRepo = new GenericRepository<IFoo>(context);
        }
        return FooRepo;
    }
}
```