# Store implementation of generic interface in list

Tags: c#, oop, generics, polymorphism, covariance

I'm trying to create a service which manages different account providers and accounts within our application (WPF desktop app).

My idea was to have account providers, which would be external web services such as Jira, Gitlab, etc. Each provider has a list with accounts.

Depending on the provider it can have different means to authorize our software to use a users account. Our first implementation is using OAuth tokens for authorization and a Rest API to interact with a web service.

Obviously, we need some restrictions e.g. an OAuthProvider will only accept OAuthAccounts in its Accounts list.

The ideal case would be if we could store all providers no matter their accounts type in a single list of the form `List<IAccountProvider<IAccount>> someList`. However I couldn't get it to compile. The error is:

`Error CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'TestProject.Program.JiraProvider' to 'TestProject.Program.IAccountProvider<TestProject.Program.IAccount>'`

I tried to make IAccountProvider covariant but this in turn restricts me very much in using the interface...

Is there some way to get it to compile using this class hierarchy? If you have a better idea how to setup the hierarchy then I'd be glad to hear your suggestions :).

```cs
static int Main(string[] args)
{
    var jiraProv = new JiraProvider();
    //var someList = new List<IAccountProvider<OAuthAccount>>();  // this would work - but it's not what I want...
    var someList = new List<IAccountProvider<IAccount>>();  // this doesn't seem to work
    someList.Add(jiraProv);     // error CS1503 cannot convert from X to Y
    return 0;
}

//-----------------
// Interfaces - details left out for brevity...
// Providers
public interface IAccountProvider<T>
    where T : IAccount
{
    List<T> Accounts { get; }
    T CurrentAccount { get; }
    void Login(T account);
}

public interface IOAuthProvider<T> : IAccountProvider<T>
    where T : IOAuthAccount
{ }

// Accounts
public interface IAccount { }
public interface IOAuthAccount : IAccount { }

//-----------------
// Implementations - details left out for brevity...
public class OAuthAccount : IOAuthAccount { }
public class JiraProvider : IOAuthProvider<OAuthAccount>
{
    public List<OAuthAccount> Accounts { get; set; }
    public OAuthAccount CurrentAccount { get; set; }
    public void Login(OAuthAccount account) { }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Casting an object to a generic interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222403/casting-an-object-to-a-generic-interface)

Comment: `List<T>` is invariant in C#, `IAccountProvider<IAccount>` is different type from `IOAuthProvider<OAuthAccount>`

Comment: I don't see how the link you posted would answer my question. Maybe I'm missing something. Is your suggestion to make the base interface non-generic?

Comment: "*List<T> is invariant in C#*" Is this the reason why it doesn't compile? I know that `IAccountProvider<IAccount>>` and `IAccountProvider<OAuthAccount>>` are different. But I thought since OAuthAccount also implements IAccount that it would be possible to store everything in a list.
Maybe I don't fully understand the notion of *different* in this context?

Comment: Generic types are resolved at runtime, not at compile time, it's one point. Second point is that your `IAccountProvider<T>` is also invariant. Have a look at [Variance in Generic Interfaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/variance-in-generic-interfaces)